# Passing parameters as expressions in postman for json query templates

Tags: sql, json, expression, hive, postman

> Hi All,
>
> I am trying to pass parameters in postman for running some query
>   templates which are basically hive/sql queries .This is how the the TemplateTable.json(which is a 
>   query template) which is
>   being passed parameters to execute from postman looks like

```
 [ 
 {   
 "templateId":  "TemplateTable",
 "description": "TemplateTable", 
 "statements":   [ "set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict",
 "DROP VIEW IF EXISTS TemplateTable",
 "CREATE VIEW TemplateTableAS
     SELECT
         /*+ MAPJOIN(m) */
         i.base_time_stamp as timestamp_utc,
         CAST(regexp_extract(i.context, ';c/4/([0-9]+)' , 1) AS INT) as source_id,
         nw_name as network,
         @{day} as day
     FROM  Table1 m
     JOIN  Table2 i ON (CAST(regexp_extract(i.context, ';c/4/([0-9]+)' , 1) AS INT) = m.source_id)"  ],

"parameters":
    [
    {"name": "day", "required": true,  "description": "day can be any day of the week with numeric codes"}
    ]
}
]
```

===========================================================================

> AT POSTMAN:
>
> {     "templateId": "TemplateTable" ,   "parameters":{"day":"CASE
>   from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(starttime), 'EEE')
>               WHEN 'Mon' THEN '01|Mon'
>               WHEN 'Tue' THEN '02|Tue'
>               WHEN 'Wed' THEN '03|Wed'
>               WHEN 'Thu' THEN '04|Thu'
>               WHEN 'Fri' THEN '05|Fri'
>               WHEN 'Sat' THEN '06|Sat'
>               WHEN 'Sun' THEN '07|Sun'
>               END    "} }
>
> even though it does not give any error message it does not create the
>   view in database Firstly ) if someone can point out how to use
>   expressions like the case above to be passed as parameter Secondly )
>   if some can provide some helpful links which show parameters being
>   passed as big expressions in postman that wold be very helpful .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but in order to POST JSON you should obviously make sure you have the correct HTTP Verb selected in the Verb drop down list.  Then click the raw tab (it's the third tab from the left, coming after form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded respectively).  From here you can paste your entire JSON contents.  Ensure that you select the correct content-type (in this case application/json).  Alternatively you can go to the binary tab and I belive upload a file.  I usually paste my JSON in the raw section though so I'm not 100% sure on how this part works.

As far as the data not showing up in the database, that's application specific and without some more details I can't help in that regard.